# rotating only a part of the image in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Sorry, I'm a complete noob when it comes to coding.
I've got a question for rotating only a portion of the image using Python. I already have PIL imported and the rotate function working but I can't make it rotate only a portion of the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from PIL import Image
import _imaging
import sys

myImage = Image.open("img.gif")

for x in range():
    for y in range():
        myImage.rotate(90).show()
```

I have something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would propose the following solution:

```
inlay = img.crop((x1,y1,x2,y2)).rotate(90)
img.paste(inlay, (x1,y1,x2,y2))
```

x1,y1 is the left upper corner and x2,y2 the lower right corner of the inlay/sub-image.

img = myImage from your example